# Where are the files created with CreateFileAsync?

Tags: c#, uwp

When I call the following function, it should create a .txt file and write a sentence in it. It seems to execute without any errors. But I cannot find where this file is stored/located after being created. I ran a Windows Search to look for the file but nothing came up. Where is this file located? Also, what is the best folder/location to put a .txt file that the program uses? Should I put it in Solution Explorer of Visual Studio or Debug folder?

```
    private async void CreateFile() {
     try {
      // Create sample file, replace if exists.
      StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
      StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

      sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("sample.txt");

      await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, "Swift as a shadow!");
     } catch (Exception ex) {
      textBox.Text = ex.ToString();
     }
    }
```

Comment: Discover it yourself displaying `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`, e.g. `textbox.Text = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`

Comment: It says "Windows.Storage.StorageFolder"

Comment: You need to read the Path property. `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path`

Comment: Looks like it's in LocalState folder deep within AppData. How would I modify the code so the file is created somewhere more easily accessible like the Debug folder or Solution Explorer?

Comment: @EsAMe That's a different question. On Stackoverflow, always ask a single precise question. This question is answered, so ask a new one and there give some more details regarding the purpose of the files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the code show the path:

```
sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("sample.txt");
await new MessageDialog(sampleFile.Path).ShowAsync();
```

On Windows 10, this will be a path like:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Packages\[Package family name]\LocalState\sample.txt
```

where username is the name of the logged on user and package family name is the package family name of your application